# ASP.NET Bundling - Bundle not updating after included file has changed or when the bundle structure is changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

Bundle works fine but does not update no matter what, even when I change the bundle structure by altering sequence of "Includes", adding "?xxxx333" [some dummy version] to file names, deleting files name from the includes. Changed contents of files. I even tried changing file name of an includes javascript file in the bundle includes, then renamed the file name in actual folder.  App threw "File not found" error.

Not sure what to do.  The bundle is just stuck and wouldn't change. I browsed around to find solutions.  Others people experienced similar issues in the past but their solutions didn't work.

This is just crazy, I have change `SriptsBundle` to `Bundle` (so that files are not automatically mimified), added `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false`. Turned off the machine several times. Changed file names... nothing has worked.  I guess my last resort is to get rid of this bundling and go back to explicit includes in files. I am just getting tired of these half cooked APIs being thrown into the market.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it likely it is being cached anywhere? e.g. browser

Comment: Not being cached by Browsers. Have tried different browsers and  different machines.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, what seemed to work is this :

```
bundles.Clear()
 bundles.ResetAll()
```

Only issue now is I can't stop the bundling from mimifying everything despite the fact I am calling Optimization = false.

Comment: Working like a charm, of course with clear() and resetall() functions.  It solved a major headache for us.  We have thousands of lines of code in javascript files (about 15 of them). many of these files are being used on different pages. Everytime we made any changes in any of these js files, we had to change the imports of these pages to change ?xxx  (after the js file name) to force borowsers to reload new js file.  It was a big pain to change all pages every time.  Now, we just change the files and the bundle refreshes itself and automatically changes its version.

Comment: where did you put this code?  in `BundleConfig.cs`?

Comment: @AndyRaddatz I am using VB .Net, so it is Global.asx.vb file. but now looking at the code, i don't see these lines. Perhaps after some updates the code started to work without it.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Searched a lot of places, and this is what did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my situation, I had a CSS file that changed (alongside the minified version) but the bundle would not update.

I noticed that there was a CSS mapping file also included in the project (even though the project on my development environment was set up to minify the CSS file but not generate a mapping file). Deleting this mapping file actually caused the bundle to refresh correctly.

I also had another issue once where I had a CSS file that was referenced in a script bundle but a minified version of that file did not exist. Even though I had the "EnableOptimizations" flag set to false in the bundle code, for some reason, the absence of that minified CSS file caused the script bundle reference in the MVC view to not update, even though it referenced the actual CSS file, not the minified version. Even after I got this working by including a minified version of that CSS file in the project, the reference in the MVC view still pointed to the original CSS file.

Long story short, the bundling code has some weird quirks (or features?) so you might have to try different combinations of things to get it to behave correctly.